# In server components, I'm unable to use dynamic data-fetching to a Route Handler when I build the Next 13 app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

In the code below:

The first dynamic request to an **outside API** works correctly both in dev mode & when I build the application.

The second dynamic request to a **Route Handler** works in dev mode, but when I try to build the application I receive this error .

> Error occurred prerendering page "/about". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-errorTypeError: fetch failed

NOTE: When the data in the second request is **cached**, I don't get the above error when building the application.

```
import Image from "next/image";

//! This is the index page of About
export default async function About() {

    //* This request works just fine
    let response1 = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random', { cache: "no-store" });
    let data1 = await response1.json() as { message: string }

    //! ERROR/ I'm unable to use dynamic data-fetching to a Route Handler when I build the Next 13 app
    let response2 = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users', { cache: "no-store" });
    let data2 = await response2.json() as { success: string, users: UserModelType[] }

    console.log(" ~ file: page.tsx:14 ~ About ~ data2:", data2)

    return (
        <>
            <h1> Welcome to About  </h1>
            <Image src={data1.message} alt="dog's image" width={400} height={200} priority={true} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is my Route handler

```
import MongodbConnection from "@/src/backend/database/mongodb";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import UserModel from "@/src/backend/database/model/AuthUsers"

MongodbConnection()
export async function GET(request: Request) {

    let origin = request.headers.get("origin");

    let users: UserModelType[] = await UserModel.find()

    return NextResponse.json({ success: "Hello, Next.js!", users }, {

        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    })
}
```

My Question is. In a server component, how can I send dynamic request to a Route Handler?

NOTE: the code below works just fine in dev mode & when I build the application.
because it's static data-fetching

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import nextImage from '@/public/images/next.svg'
import AddUser from '@/src/components/AddUser';
import ShowData from '@/src/components/showData';

//! Setting a revalidation for the entire route instead of setting them on the fetch request itself, or in case if you're not use the fetch API
export const revalidate = 10

export default async function Home() {

    //? This works
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users');
    let data = await response.json() as { success: string, users: UserModelType[] }

    return (

        <div className='Home'>
            <h1> Home Page </h1>
            <Image src={nextImage} alt='next' width={200} height={200} priority={true} />

            <ShowData users={data.users} />
            <AddUser />
        </div>
    )
}
```